# mailto: email distribution list?

Tags: html-email, mailto

I'm trying to create an HTML link that will send an email via mailto to an email distribution list. It seems when I click the link, I get a blank page and then nothing happens. My mail app doesn't pop-up.

My HTML is correct as when I replace the email distribution list (distro@sample.com) with my personal email (personal@sample.com), my mail app registers this activity and pops-up.

I'm not too familiar with the rules of mailto to an email distribution list vs. an email address, or if there are any. Is there a way to set up an email distribution list so that others can't "mailto" them?

Thanks in advance for any advice or insight.

Comment: What program are you trying to use? What operating system?

Comment: Are you using one email address that forwards to your distribution list? Or are you listing multiple addresses in your "mailto"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why a mailto wouldn't work for a distro list, but if it is a not a huge list you can try [adding Carbon Copies](https://support.exclaimer.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360029340851-Adding-CC-BCC-Subjects-Bodys-to-mailto-hyperlinks) for everyone on the list to the mailto